# Using fzf in a zle key binding

Tags: zsh, zle, fzf

I have the following function in my `.zshrc`

```
function foo() {
    filename="$(fzf)"
}
zle -N foo
bindkey '^X' foo
```

now if I call `foo` by typing it, it works as expected, but if I call it via the key-binding with `^X`, the `fzf` buffer is empty.

Can anyone reproduce this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the point is to insert the output of `fzf` at the current cursor position, properly quoted, it should be something like:

```
insert-quoted-fzf-output() {
  local output
  output=$(fzf</dev/tty) && LBUFFER+=${(q-)output}
}

zle -N insert-quoted-fzf-output
bindkey '^X' insert-quoted-fzf-output
```

That is you need to insert that output at the end of `$LBUFFER` (the part of the editing buffer left of the cursor), quoted (here using the `q-` parameter expansion flag to minimise the amount of quoting), and you need `fzf` to take its input from the terminal. You probably want the widget to return a non-zero exit status if `fzf` fails.

Your specific problem about *empty `fzf` buffer* here was about the missing `</dev/tty` redirection.

You'll notice the same behaviour of `fzf` if you run it as `fzf < /dev/null`.

If you run `info zsh widgets` (assuming you have the `zsh` documentation available in `info` format; on some systems, you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package), you'll see (emphasis mine):

> ### 18.5 User-Defined Widgets
>
> User-defined widgets, being implemented as shell functions, can execute
> any normal shell command.  They can also run other widgets (whether
> built-in or user-defined) using the `zle` builtin command.  **The standard
> input of the function is redirected from /dev/null to prevent external
> commands from unintentionally blocking ZLE by reading from the terminal**,
> but `read -k` or `read -q` can be used to read characters.

When its stdin is not a terminal, `fzf` reads it to construct the list of choices to offer to its user. `/dev/null` is a special device where any attempt to read anything returns with nothing, which explains why you get an empty buffer. Restoring a terminal there makes it switch back to the mode where instead of reading stdin for the list of choices, it reads the output of a  `$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` command (some `find` command by default).

Another option would be to actually run that `find` command by yourself. If you're on a GNU system, you could even improve on it to add a bit more of reliability and efficiency:

```
output=$(
  LC_ALL=C find -L . -name . -o '(' \
    -name '.*' -o \
    -fstype sysfs -o \
    -fstype devfs -o \
    -fstype devtmpfs -o \
    -fstype proc ')' -prune -o -type f -printf '%P\0' 2> /dev/null |
    fzf --read0 --print0
) && output=${output%$'\0'}
```

Comment: The part I needed was just `</dev/tty`. Could you explain what that does and why no output is shown without it?

Comment: @noibe, see edit.